# Count And Group By Using

Tags: oracle, group-by, count

Not the number of values grouped by group by. How can I print the number of rows of the result of this query?

```
SELECT F.BELTAR FROM E_HDFTKP_FORM F
INNER JOIN E_HDFTKP_FORM_TABLO3 S ON F.ID = S.FORMID
INNER JOIN FLOWDOCUMENTS FD ON F.ID = FD.FILEPROFILEID
INNER JOIN LIVEFLOWS LF ON FD.PROCESSID = LF.ID
INNER JOIN FLOWSTATUSES FL ON LF.FLOWVERSION = FL.VERSION AND FL.STATUS = LF.STATUS AND FL.PROCESS = LF.PROCESS
WHERE F.BELGENO IS NOT NULL  AND LF.FLOWSTEP > 1 AND S.HAT2 = 'T101' AND LF.DELETED = 0  
GROUP BY F.BELTAR
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample? It would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> Not the number of values grouped by group by. How can I print the number of rows of the result of this query?

Wrap your query inside a sub-query and then `COUNT` the rows:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
  SELECT F.BELTAR
  FROM   E_HDFTKP_FORM F
         INNER JOIN E_HDFTKP_FORM_TABLO3 S
         ON F.ID = S.FORMID
         INNER JOIN FLOWDOCUMENTS FD
         ON F.ID = FD.FILEPROFILEID
         INNER JOIN LIVEFLOWS LF
         ON FD.PROCESSID = LF.ID
         INNER JOIN FLOWSTATUSES FL
         ON     LF.FLOWVERSION = FL.VERSION
            AND FL.STATUS = LF.STATUS
            AND FL.PROCESS = LF.PROCESS
  WHERE  F.BELGENO IS NOT NULL
  AND    LF.FLOWSTEP > 1
  AND    S.HAT2 = 'T101'
  AND    LF.DELETED = 0  
  GROUP BY F.BELTAR
)
```

If the `BELTAR` values are unique within the `E_HDFTKP_FORM` then it may be more efficient to use `EXISTS` to correlate with the other tables than to use `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   E_HDFTKP_FORM F
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   E_HDFTKP_FORM_TABLO3 S
         WHERE  F.ID = S.FORMID
         AND    S.HAT2 = 'T101'
       )
AND    EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   FLOWDOCUMENTS FD
                INNER JOIN LIVEFLOWS LF
                ON FD.PROCESSID = LF.ID
                INNER JOIN FLOWSTATUSES FL
                ON     LF.FLOWVERSION = FL.VERSION
                   AND FL.STATUS = LF.STATUS
                   AND FL.PROCESS = LF.PROCESS
         WHERE  F.ID = FD.FILEPROFILEID
         AND    LF.FLOWSTEP > 1
         AND    LF.DELETED = 0
       )
WHERE  F.BELGENO IS NOT NULL
```

If the `BELTAR` values are duplicated within the `E_HDFTKP_FORM` then you may be able to use `COUNT(DISTINCT BELTAR)`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT BELTAR)
FROM   E_HDFTKP_FORM F
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   E_HDFTKP_FORM_TABLO3 S
         WHERE  F.ID = S.FORMID
         AND    S.HAT2 = 'T101'
       )
AND    EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   FLOWDOCUMENTS FD
                INNER JOIN LIVEFLOWS LF
                ON FD.PROCESSID = LF.ID
                INNER JOIN FLOWSTATUSES FL
                ON     LF.FLOWVERSION = FL.VERSION
                   AND FL.STATUS = LF.STATUS
                   AND FL.PROCESS = LF.PROCESS
         WHERE  F.ID = FD.FILEPROFILEID
         AND    LF.FLOWSTEP > 1
         AND    LF.DELETED = 0
       )
WHERE  F.BELGENO IS NOT NULL
```